# If $f:X\to Y$ is continuous and surjective, and $X$ is metrizable, so is $Y$?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

The question is that. I have a continuous map $f:X\to Y$ such that $f(X)=Y$. If $X$ is metrizable, then $Y$ is metrizable?

Or at least, can we say that $Y$ is homeomorphic to a metrizable space?

I think the answer is no, but I don't know exactly why.

Thanks.

Comment: Consider the simplest example of a non-metrisable space you can think of for $Y$.

Comment: Perhaps better to assume that $Y$ has the finest topology such that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: If $Y$ is homeomorphic to a metrizable space, then it is metrizable :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about a map onto any non-metrizable space via the identity map from the same underlying set with the discrete topology?

Answer (score 1):

The quotient space of $\mathbb R$ under the two equivalence classes $[0, \infty)$ and $(-\infty, 0)$ defines a non-Hausdorff topological space $Q$ with two points, equipped with a projection map $\pi: \mathbb R \to Q$. Here the only nontrivial open subset of $Q$ is the singleton $\{(-\infty, 0)\}$.

This example can be modified easily to give a quotient space of $\mathbb R$ with the indiscrete topology.

Answer (score 0):

Take $X$ an infinite dimensional normed space and $Y$ the same space in its weak topology.
Every weak-open is also open, thus the identity $I: X\to Y$ is continuous.

The interesting question is the inverse: If $Y$ is metrizable and $f: X\to Y$ is onto, then what can we tell about $X$?